# Descendents layouts not appearing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I'm trying to define more than one LinearLayout to fit a form and a button bar at the bottom of my activity but it's not appearing, before my changes all the forms was with `ScrollView`, but I removed that because I will not use anymore, but when I removed my layout is not appearing anymore, anyone has any solutions what I did wrong ? or forget ?

Here is my new code, but when I turn the orientation to landscape my buttons disappear. how can I fix that ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Cliente:  "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <br.com.stara.iris.mobile.tmp.DelayAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/nota_cliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="2"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/nota_cliente_loading_indicator"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_default"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Dados do Dispositivo:  "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/dadosdispo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Número de Série:  "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nota_numeroserie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Digite o n° serie"
            android:maxLength="18" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Descrição: "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nota_descricao"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:hint="Digite a descrição"
             />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_nota_itenslist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Itens" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_nota_ordenslist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Ordens" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_nota_limpar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Limpar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_nota_salvar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Salvar" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here its what I want, but when turns the landscape mode my buttons don't disappear, and I could figure out in this way but I don't know if is right or not.

[image]

and with the tag  `android:gravity="center|bottom"` I wish to set these bar button in the `last line` of my activity the last widget bar lets say these way, but I'm not figuring out how?

And also how can I split by equal the size of the buttons to fit the size of the screen ?

Comment: can u post a picture what u want ?

Comment: off course just updated...

Comment: The xml you posted is the current one?

Comment: yes it is these one i'm using right now, i need to fix the issue of changing the screen tipe / portrait x landscape and the size of the buttons

Comment: @TheRedFox do you have any ideas what can i do ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only need to change `layout_height` to `0dp` of `ScrollView` apply a **weight 1** not for `LinearLayout`(which is inside ScrollView) do like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Cliente:  "
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <br.com.stara.iris.mobile.tmp.DelayAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/nota_cliente"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="2"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/nota_cliente_loading_indicator"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_default"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Dados do Dispositivo:  "
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/dadosdispo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Número de Série:  "
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nota_numeroserie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Digite o n° serie"
                android:maxLength="18" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Descrição: "
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nota_descricao"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:hint="Digite a descrição" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_nota_itenslist"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="Itens" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_nota_ordenslist"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="Ordens" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_nota_limpar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="Limpar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_nota_salvar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="Salvar" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot man, it works, and with this xml i'm populating a fragment and actually when my app starts, start in portrait mode, but if a change the perspective my app crash do you have any idea why this happens ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try Relative Layout.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Cliente:  "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <br.com.stara.iris.mobile.tmp.DelayAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/nota_cliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="2"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/nota_cliente_loading_indicator"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_default"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Dados do Dispositivo:  "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/dadosdispo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Número de Série:  "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nota_numeroserie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Digite o n° serie"
            android:maxLength="18" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Descrição: "
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nota_descricao"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:hint="Digite a descrição" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_nota_itenslist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Itens" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_nota_ordenslist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Ordens" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_nota_limpar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Limpar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_nota_salvar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:text="Salvar" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot man, it works, and with this xml i'm populating a fragment and actually when my app starts, start in portrait mode, but if a change the perspective my app crash do you have any idea why this happens ?